# using a json file to create a table in html

Tags: javascript, python, html, json

I realise that this question has been asked a lot. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to work out how to properly implement any of the solutions.

So I have 3 files all in the same folder. 1 python script that creates the json file based on data scraped online.

Python script:

```
jsonFile = {"title": bookTitle, "author": author}
jsonArray.append(jsonFile)
with open(data.json, 'w) as file:
    json.dump(jsonArray, file)
```

The JSON file ends up looking like this:

```
[{"name": "Foo", "author": "bar"},
{"name": "Bart", "author": "Simpson"},
 {"name": "Homer", "author": "Simpson"}]
```

Now I'm trying to get that data into my index.html and to display it in various ways such as a table.

Index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="table-container">
    <table id="table">
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Author</th>
       </tr>
      </table>
      </div></div>
     <script>
        var data = $.getJSON(data.json);
        var table = document.getElementById("table");

        data.forEach(function(object)  {
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.innerHTML = "<td>" + object.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + object.author + "</td>"
            table.appendChild(tr);
        });
</script></body>
```

I appreciate any pointers someone might be able to give. Side question: do I need to use JQuery? Is there a better way?

Comment: You do **not** need to use jQuery. But using jQuery to make an ajax-request is most of the times easier to use.

Comment: The return value of `getJSON` is not an array. It does not have a `forEach` method. Nor does it make any sense to pass `data.json` to `getJSON` since you haven't defined `data.json` in the first place.

Comment: You have the wrong field name in the code, you are using `object.title`, but in the JSON file, it is `name`. Also, you don't need jQuery to accomplish this, it is unnecessary bloat. Refer to this guide on how to work with JSON data in Javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Answer (score 0):

Checking if you need jQuery is easy via http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Based on their recommendation your JS-code would look like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'data.json', true);

request.onload = function () {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response); //this is your JSON that is returned from your API (python)
        var table = document.querySelector('#table');

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');

            tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + object.title + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.author + '</td>'
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
    } else {
        // ERROR!!
    }
};

request.onerror = function () {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```